# Sharepoint keeps synchronising shared columns in document set

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a recurring problem with Sharepoints shared columns that keep on synchronising.
I have multiple document libraries in which I reference the same document set.
In that document set I have set up shared columns + default folders and documents.

When I create a new document set and fill in the metadata at the root level, it takes forever to cascade this information down to the documents within it. When I say forever, it takes days and days and sometimes it doesn't even complete the task.

I have attached a picture of the synchronising icon that keeps on going.
Does someone know how I can solve this problem?
Thank you very very much!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzI24.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that the shared column of documents in the document set will automatically be filled in the same value as document set. Is it right?

This is what the shared column does, and it's a normal phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks for responding.                                                                                                               I understand that the shared columns in a document set should cascade the information down to the documents, I want that but the problem is that this is not working for my Sharepoint. It keeps synchronizing and doesn't fill in the data.